# Drupal Date Filed Problem

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I am using custom module in drupal and i am working in `hook_form_alter()` .

I am passing date format as this type.

But it is not working and filed type is DATETIME.

Please help  me...

```
$form['field_res_inq_time_arrival'][0]['#default_value']['value'] = date('d/m/Y - h:m',strtotime('2011/04/13'));
```

Regards 

Aasim Afridi

Answer (score 1):

From [Form Api Reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#date):

> The #default_value will be today's date if no value is supplied. The format for the #default_value and the #return_value is an array with three elements with the keys: 'year', month', and 'day'. For example, array('year' => 2007, 'month' => 2, 'day' => 15)